# JS Regex match Canadian postal code from string

Tags: javascript, regex, postal-code

I would like to find the alphanumeric canadian postal code from a string.
A string such as `H9B2R1|taco|salsa|taco` or if encoded, `H9B2R1%7Ctaco%7Csalsa%7Ctaco`.
The result I'm looking for is the trimmed postal code before any special characters and/or non-alphanumeric values.
How to I use split or regex to parse/match this to return `H9B2R1` ? I searched stackoverflow for a question like this, but didn't find any.

Comment: Have you tried splitting with `|` and getting the first item? `"H9B2R1|taco|salsa|taco".split('|')[0]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the selected answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
"H9B2R1|taco|salsa|taco".match(/\w+/)[0] //returns H9B2R1
"H9B2R1%7Ctaco%7Csalsa%7Ctaco".match(/\w+/)[0] //returns H9B2R1

//or using split method

"H9B2R1|taco|salsa|taco".split(/\W/)[0] //returns H9B2R1
"H9B2R1%7Ctaco%7Csalsa%7Ctaco".split(/\W/)[0] //returns H9B2R1
```